# Missing matches in match collection

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching, wildcard

I have few user inputs which I am trying to compare via MatchCollection with different patterns I have i.e

```
string user = "\b(?:I|would|like|to|see|id|of|bought|good)\b";
```

but When I am matching string

```
string pattern = "^(?=.*\bgoods?|items?|things?\b)(?=.*\bbought\b)(?=.*\bid\b)(?=.*\btest\b).*$";

MatchCollection mat = Regex.Matches(pattern , user );

foreach (var item in mat)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

When matching the two above, the match collection only yields/collects match for (id, bought) but ignores "goods" from the first block of pattern. It seems to be ignoring **?** lookahead mentioned goods?|items?|things?.

Any suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand which string is the pattern and which is the actual string, if indeed any of these are the actual strings.

Comment: Looking at your last 2 questions, you are on the wrong track. This is not the job of regex.

Comment: Sorry guys, I have amended the question.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? We could spend a while debugging a weird regex (seriously, only lookaheads?), but I'd rather solve the actual problem.

Comment: I have written plenty of pattern as part of Conversational Agent (CA) test program. The users will ask questions and CA will answer back. But in the event where user miss something in utterance so function will pick up only partial match and suggest users about missed part to be entered for full/complete match. As partial match on its own would be not certain answer for the CA.

Comment: Then split the input into *words*, after that decide with one is missing using .Net data structures or Linq.

Comment: Good idea thanks. Do you know what might be causing the problem in    matching **good** from this block i have mentioned **?** after every word (?=.*\bgoods?|items?|things?\b). I can now match even goods so it working but its just that it would not with positive lookahead at the end of every word. thanks

Comment: I am taking every User's Input and reformatting in this way for it to be used in match collection.